# Symfony2 - Get Form value, not key

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony2 (version 2.7) and I'm trying to get the value from a submitted form. Using `$form->getData()`, I get the index corresponding to the selected value in the list.

For example, assuming $test is an array:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($test)
->add('abc', 'choice',
    array('choices' => array(
        '0' => 'option1',
        '1' => 'option2',
        '2' => 'option3'
    )))
->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $data = ($form->getData());
}
```

Then, `$data` will be `1` if I select `option2`. 
I've also tried to set `choices_as_values` to true, but then I got the array indexes in the drop-down list.

What can I do to get `$data` equal to `option2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$values = array('option1', 'option2', 'option3');

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($test)
->add('abc', 'choice', array('choices' => $values))
->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form['abc']->getData();

    //returns option1 if option1 is selected etc..
    $choice = $values[$data];

    //returns choice value
    $choice = $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Worked like a charm.